# not matching distribution for scann

Tags: python, scann

I´m stuck for several days was trying to install tflite-model-maker. Now my mostrcent showstopper is I cannot install scaNN via pip, (nor conda).
I tried under enviroments with python 3.10, 3.19, 3.8, all in windows 10.

I read that scann is a linux lib which doest work in Windows. Ok, I tried to install from my hosted linux server, in a fresh enviroment which doesnt have many libraries installed. The result was exactly the as as in windows:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scann==1.2.6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scann==1.2.6
```

I read that it works in WSL, great, I tried to install scann from a virtual env on Cygwin. Same result.

Bottom line: pip cannot fint scaNN neither from Windows, Cygwin nor Linux server.

I dont know how to check if the lib is available, or maybe which kind of requirements do I need to install before.

Any light to this poor lost soul?

Comment: from [here](https://pypi.org/project/scann/#files), you can see there's only Linux version available for pip packages. Yet, there's still hope which is to build this project from source, but the process might not be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to install python 3.7 in a conda env and do not forget the audio package required for tflite-model-make.